# PDF converter for Classic ASP Application?

Tags: pdf, converters

I need my asp page (report) to be converted as PDF format. Is there any free 3rd party control available for Classic ASP?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

It uses webkit.

Basically it's an EXE. You can call it from ASP (starting a process) and then sending the output file in the response stream.

Answer (score 0):

active pdf and websupergoo are good choices.
Another option is the Adobe FDF toolkit.  The fdf toolkit is cool because it lets you store pdf form data, can be saved in a db, and then it populates a pdf.